# Chinese word becomes messy code when using fastinsert for the MySql

Tags: mysql, matlab

I need to read some records from a table in mysql and then write into another table.

First, I use the code to read records:

```
sql = 'select * ....';
cursor = fetch(exec(conn, sql));
```

The code can fetch the data, and the chinese field is very clearly. After this, I need to write the data into another table.

```
cursor{end+1} = 'test';
fastinsert(conn, tablename, colname, cursor);
```

The code can write the data into the specified table. BUT the chinese words become messy code. I don't know why.

What's more. I have tried:

```
 1) insert a record using phpmyadmin manually,  and the chinese word is clearly.
 2) change the default character set of mysql to 'utf-8',but the error exists as well
```

So,I guess whether I need to do some character set relevant operations or not before insertion. And how to do it? :-)

Any suggestion will be thankful!

Answer (score 0):

I have figure out this question.

```
1) set the mysql charset utf8
  set names 'utf8'

2) specify the matlab connection charset ''utf8''
  append useUnicode=true&charset=utf8 on the database url
```